# Can i run a gwt project without using a webserver

Tags: python, gwt

Im making a webserver from scratch in python by simply supplying HTML content through a tcp socket. I want to be able to run gwt projects, is this possible by just echoing the contents of the generated index.html to a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a client-side GWT application, then yes, you could serve it with a basic HTTP webserver that receives HTTP GET requests from a browser and serves files like HTML, JavaScript, images, etc.

If the GWT application includes server-side servlets then it wouldn't work when the client sent requests to the server part of the application.